# Get parent id from child record EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using MVC + C# + EF Code First

I have a child record that I retrieve using its ID.
I would like to then get the ID of its parent

I can see the parent_id in the database but can't seem to expose it in C#

Is there any way to get this?
Thanks

Comment: Your questions is such that we cannot quite help you. Can you post the parent and child classes? You need to give more information. This is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use code-first approach. It would be nice to see your implementation of MyDbContext. Usually, you sould have a virtual Parent property in your Child class:

```
public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the code you can access the Id of the parent like:

```
Child child = ...;
var parentId = child.Parent.Id;
```

Comment: my implementation is per the other comment - but without the public virtual key- looks like that's where I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing the public virtual Parent.in the child class.  Without it EF created a foreign key but apparently its not accessible that way.  I'll give this a try .. Thanks!