# Using EF is there a built-in process to reference the parent of the parent?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

The answer at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893860/get-parent-id-from-child-record-ef) is one of many that show how to gain access, in the code, to the parent of a child.  A major advantage of this is that the database engine sets the parent ID reference so it is always correct.

My question regards how to access the parent of the parent in similar fashion, and if EF doesn't have a convention for this, is there a proven pattern that works best to do this?

I have a tiered database structure that runs 4-deep like this:

```
Class 1
  includes a list of Class 2
Class 2
  includes a list of Class 3
Class 3
  includes a list of Class 4
Class 4
```

In EF I can easily add a Foreign Key reference in the code for each parent.

If I want to have access to the entire structure from any point in the hierarchy, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: That answer you link is what you need, you just need a double hop, like `foo.Parent.GrandParent`

Comment: I thought that might be the answer, but you don't know until someone confirms it for you.  Thx.  So when I use a query to bring in data, I always have to `include` all tables, bringing in the entire hierarchy, as opposed to being able to have a property in, say Class 4, that refers to its Class 1 ancestor.